# duplicated file is not showed in scrapy

Tags: scrapy, python

This code was working before

```
class CustomFilter(RFPDupeFilter):

    def request_seen(self, request):
        fp = request.url
        if fp in self.fingerprints: #if this condition is true, we have visited this url before
            logging.log(logging.INFO, "Ignoring url=%r" % request.url)
            return True
        else: #if this condition is true, we are about to scrap a details page url
            self.fingerprints.add(fp)
            logging.log(logging.INFO, "Scrpaing url=%r" % request.url)
            if self.file:
                self.file.write(fp + os.linesep)
            else:
                print("why is that happending?")
            return False
```

I specify the duplicated class in my settings, and I keep getting "why is that happening?" that's because the file is not there.

I read the official code of the RFPDupeFilter, and there should already be a file called request.seen, but for some reasons, it's not being generated :(

Comment: Is this post related to this site ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about computer programming, not the English language.

Comment: On topic (except that proofreading is off topic), in line 10, you probably want "scraping" instead of "scrpaing"; In line 14 you probably want "happening" instead of "happending"; in line 8 you probably want "scrape" instead of "scrap".